# How to display images from Resource.rc in Dear ImGui framework?

Tags: c++, imgui

I want to display an image from `Resource.rc` file when I'm using `Dear ImGui` framework.

I have my code here.

```
HRSRC resource = FindResourceW(GCM(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1), MAKEINTRESOURCE("PGN"));
HANDLE image = LoadResource(GCM(), resource);
int imageWidth = 810;
int imageHeight = 701;
ImGui::Image(image, ImVec2(imageWidth, imageHeight));


inline HMODULE GCM() {
    HMODULE hmodule = NULL;
    GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, (LPCTSTR)GCM, &hmodule);
    return hmodule;
}
```

But when I display my image, it's all black. The data type of `HANDLE` is `void*` and the first argument of `ImGui::Image` want to have the void pointer data type as well.

I have added two files into my `Resource.rc` file.

[image]

The `resource.h` header file looks like this.

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by Resource.rc
//
#define IDB_PNG1                        101
#define IDI_ICON1                       102

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        103
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

And the `Resource.rc` file looks like this

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Swedish (Sweden) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_SVE)
LANGUAGE LANG_SWEDISH, SUBLANG_SWEDISH
#pragma code_page(1252)

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// PNG
//

IDB_PNG1                PNG                     "pinmap.png"


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "logo.ico"

#endif    // Swedish (Sweden) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

**Question:**

How can I display an image by loading it from the resources and include that image in ImGui framwork?

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment yet - I asked the same question over on the Dear ImGui github and got some responses that may help you.  I haven't solved it on my end yet, but plan to in the near future.

https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/6205

Gist:

> What you want is (1) create an .rc file to collect your resources (such as this one) and (2) load the resource internally as a data pointer you can then inject into whatever library you want.

> There are many ways to achieve similar things, eg we embed ProggyClean in the source code using our own binary_to_c tool helper located in the misc/ folder, but there are many more or less elaborate alternatives to that. Search for “embed binary in C sources”.